# Complicated datetime merge pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assume that I have the following data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 28), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 12), 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 28), 1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id'])

table2 = [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 
          datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30), 
          datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30)]
```

Is there a way to merge `table2` onto `table` such that the elements of `table2` are joined on the closest but smallest than or equal element of `table`, and then fill the table backwards? This also needs to be done groupwise on the column `Id`. As an example, the resulting table would be

```
         Date  Id  New
0  2015-01-01   1  2015-03-31
1  2015-01-27   1  2015-03-31
2  2015-01-31   1  2015-03-31
3  2015-02-01   1  2015-03-31
4  2015-02-03   1  2015-03-31
5  2015-02-15   1  2015-03-31
6  2015-02-28   1  2015-03-31
7  2015-03-01   1  2015-03-31
8  2015-03-17   1  2015-03-31
9  2015-03-28   1  2015-03-31
10 2015-04-12   1  2015-06-30
11 2015-04-28   1  2015-06-30
```

Thanks, Tingis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
table2 = pd.to_datetime(table2)
idx = table2.searchsorted(df['Date'].values)
```

This finds the indices where the dates in `df['Date']` should be inserted into `table2` while maintaining sorted order. Note that this assumes `table2` starts out in sorted order.

---

```
table2 = pd.to_datetime(table2)
idx = table2.searchsorted(df['Date'].values)
df['New'] = table2[idx]
print(df)
```

yields

```
         Date  Id        New
0  2015-01-01   1 2015-03-31
1  2015-01-27   1 2015-03-31
2  2015-01-31   1 2015-03-31
3  2015-02-01   1 2015-03-31
4  2015-02-03   1 2015-03-31
5  2015-02-15   1 2015-03-31
6  2015-02-28   1 2015-03-31
7  2015-03-01   1 2015-03-31
8  2015-03-17   1 2015-03-31
9  2015-03-28   1 2015-03-31
10 2015-04-12   1 2015-06-30
11 2015-04-28   1 2015-06-30
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Will this work groupwise as well? Such that if I have the same df but twice as big where half have `Id = 1` and the rest `Id=2`?

Comment: Yes, it can work inside of a groupby operation too. One thing to be careful about, however, is that `table2` should contain a date bigger than any in `df['Date']`. Otherwise the index it returns will be out of range, causing an IndexError in `table2[idx]`. There are other ways to address this problem, such as using `np.clip`, but first you have to decide what the desired result should be when a date in `df['Date']` is larger than any in `table2`...

Comment: Ah, great, thanks! Okay, will have that in mind. And I think this constraint will be avoidable by default. I'm trying to let a person using my script specify four measuring times themselves